# Get data from API json multiple url's into html table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

i make a script which get data and append it into html table in JavaScript
The problem is that i have multiple page url like https://myAPI?param=2&perPage=100&**page=1**(page2,page3 etc) and i have pages like this amount 300 pages

How i can get data from all pages of my API?

here my code, the problem is that only small amount of urls work, if i paste more urls, its not work

```js
var urls = ['https://myAPI?param=2&perPage=100&page=1', 'https://myAPI?param=2&perPage=100&page=2', 'https://myAPI?param=2&perPage=100&page=3',
'https://myAPI?param=2&perPage=100&page=4',
'https://myAPI?param=2&perPage=100&page=5',
'https://myAPI?param=2&perPage=100&page=6',
]


$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON(urls, function(data){
    var product_data = '';
$.each(data.items, function (i, items) {
    

        product_data += '<tr>';
        product_data += '<td>'+ items.gimaId + '</td>';
        product_data += '<td>'+ items.id + '</td>';
        product_data += '<td><a target="_blank" href="url/' + items.code + '">' + items.title + '</a> </td>';
        product_data += '<td>'+ items.categoryCodes.code + '</br>'  + items.categoryCodes.name +'</td>';
        product_data += '<td>'+ items.vendorCode + '</td>';

        product_data += '<td>'+ items.price.value + '</td>';
        product_data += '<td>'+ items.stock.qty + '</td>';
        product_data += '<td><a target = "_blank" href="url' + items.catalogImageId + "/" + '">' + items.catalogImageId + '</a></td>';
        product_data += '<td>'+ items.description.content + '</td>';
        product_data += '<td>'+ items.active + '</td>';
        product_data += '<td>'+ items.storageAddress + '</td>';
        product_data += '</tr>';
});

    

$('#showData').append(product_data);

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="showData" class="tavle">
<tr>

    <th>id</th>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>id</th>
    
  
    
</tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the pages using a for loop.
Example:

```
var pages = 0;
var url = 'https://myAPI?param=2&perPage=100&page=';
for(var i = 0; pages < 300; i++) {
    newUrl = url + i;
}
```